# Plot signal with different frequencies

Tags: matlab

I need to plot on matlab a simple x(t) function that changes its freqency after specific time:

x(t) = cos(2pi*2hz*t) for t<1;
x(t) = cos(2pi*5hz*t) for t>=1

I managed by using a simple IF statement on a function, but seems like I have to use some existing matlab function that does the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as easy as this:

```
t1=0:0.01:1;
t2=1:0.01:2;

x1=cos(2*pi*2*t1);
x2=cos(2*pi*5*t2);

hold on
plot(t1,x1,'b')
plot(t2,x2,'b')
```

[image]

**EDIT** : As @Dan suggested, if you want the whole signal to be in one variable so you can do some SCIENCE with it, youo can also do:

```
t1=0:0.01:1;
t2=1:0.01:2;

x1=cos(2*pi*2*t1);
x2=cos(2*pi*5*t2);

x=[x1 x2];
t=[t1 t2];


plot(t,x)
```

Comment: I suggest concatenation as an alternative to `hold on` so `t=[t1, t2]` and `x=[x1,x2]` then just `plot(t,x)`